# MVC in jquery, Multiple data requests from model but single callback needed

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, jquery-plugins, models

Basically the setup is almost the same as [[ [One callback for multiple json requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959680/one-callback-for-multiple-json-requests) ]], but I think the solution is too hacky and that it should be handle-able in a cleaner way in MVC.

'Tickets' and 'People' are distinct models and there is a getAll method to each. I need  to initialize a plugin with data from both getAll methods. They could be ajax requests, but I want to make it oblivious to the plugin caller. I can't think of a way, but I have no experience in MVC, any help guys? Or how should I clean it so that the mvc is cleaner?

I am trying to go after something like [this](http://welcome.totheinter.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-jquery/). Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.when(Tickets.getAll(), People.getAll()).then(function(data) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = ...
});
```

Make sure that `.getAll` returns a `$.Deferred` object so you can abstract away whether loading your models is asynchronous or not.

Comment: aha! awesome, I hadn't known if this before! While reading up on it, I came across [link](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/) where there is an example in the very end which does not return `$.Deffered` objects. Its almost the same as my situation here. Could you explain why each `getAll` should return such an object?

Comment: @SanjeevSatheesh $.when needs $.Deferred objects as parameters for it to work. You can resolve your deferred object with your model data when you've loaded it. When both are resolved you'll run your then function

Comment: I am quoting from the page here _When $.when() recognizes that its first argument doesn’t have a promise (and therefore is not observable), it creates a new deferred object, resolves it with the data, and returns the promise from the deferred._

Comment: @SanjeevSatheesh then it's resolved _immediatly_ and doesn't wait for your ajax code to load the model.

Comment: I see! thanks for the clarification. if I could +1 once more, I would :)